# React parallax effect libraries are breaking my app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, parallax

Can someone who used with success a ReactJs parallax effect library, please  please point me to it?

I have tried all of them from this article [Top 10 React Parallax Plugins with Demo](http://voidcanvas.com/top-10-react-parallax-plugins-with-demo/) and none of them seem to work in my React/Material-UI app.

I want to recreate the youtube behavior from the channel banner, that shows when you are visiting a channel.(banner simply scrolls slower then the rest of the page).

Anybody used one with success?

Comment: If none of the "top 10 parallax plugins" work, you probably have some misunderstanding of how to use them, or the problem is with your site. There's not enough information in your question to help you. Without looking too hard, [this one](http://react-lazy-hero.danielstefanovic.com/) looks like exactly what you want. It looks simple to implement.

Comment: I already tried it, and did it again now. It simply isn't there, i can't even see the DOM nodes of it with inspector.

Comment: You're probably making a basic mistake. Try making a new project using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and very carefully try out the parallax library by itself.

Comment: there is another library that needs to be installed, and it's not mentioned anywhere in that link. "npm install --save styled-components" this did the trick after installing the actual library. Thank you for making me give it another try!

Comment: You're welcome. So, the "basic mistake" you made is not reading your console output when installing the library the first time. When I install it with `yarn`, I get: `warning " > react-lazy-hero@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "styled-components@^2.1.2".` - `npm` surely provides a similar warning.

Comment: I did read it but i thought it's a who knows what library since its not mentioned on their website. It seemed important enough to be mentioned if needed, so i just moved on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181086/discussion-between-index-jsx-and-thirtydot).